# Curve passing through three points in android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, curve, bezier

What i actually want is , with the help of three points i need to draw a curve passing through all the three points. I can acheive this by using ".Path.cubicTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3)" method **but** in this scenario my middle point does not lie on the curve.
I need to draw a **"︶"** shaped curve and not like **"V"** shaped curve. i.e. the the curve must be curved at every point on the curve.

Comment: use a Catmull-Rom curve. It's another kind of Hermite curve that goes *through* points instead of being spanned by them and needing complicated math to figure out where the curve hull is. If you really want to go with Bezier curves, which I don't recommend, head over to http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#moulding + next section.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have three points `D0(x0,y0)`, `D1(x1,y1)`, `D2(x2,y2)`.
We also have to find Bezier cubic spline `P0-P1-P2-P3` passing through `D0`, `D1` and `D2`.

Obviously,

```
P0 = D0
P3 = D2
```

Then there are infinitive number of Bezier splines passing through point `D1` defined by equation

```
P2 = (D1 - (1-t)^3 * P0 - t^3 * P3) / (3*(1-t)*t^2) -
     (1-t) * P1/t;
```

where `t` is Bezier curve parameter corresponding to point `D1`.

To find a real curve, we should assign some `t`, for simplicity, let's take `t = 0.5` and choose `P1`. Then `P2` can be found from the equation above.

Here is a solution based on restriction that `P1-P2` is parallel to `D0-D2`:

```
% vector pointing from D0 to D2
baseSides = 0.3 * (D2 - D0)
% vector moving D1 towards D0 - D2 base
baseDown = 0.1 * (D0 - D1) + (D2 - D1))
% moving D1 down to the base and split to left and right
P1" = D1 + baseDown - baseSides
P2" = D1 + baseDown + baseSides
P1' = P1" + (P1" - D1) * 2 / 3
P2' = P2" + (P2" - D1) * 2 / 3
P1 = P1' + P1' - D0
P2 = P2' + P2' - D2
```

then you can use `P1`, `P2` and `P3` coordinates as parameters for `Path.cubicTo()`. 0.3 is a scaling factor here, changing it makes curve wider-narrower.

These computations are based on De Casteljau's algorithm for Bezier curve splitting.

[image: Bezier spline passing through a point]

here red diamonds are `P1"` and `P2"`, green diamonds are `P1'` and `P2'` and blue circles are `P1` and `P2`.